# URI::InvalidURIError not causing test to pass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I'm attempting to get a test to pass when an invalid URL is supplied:

```
it "is invalid when URL format is NOT valid" do
  entity = FactoryGirl.build(:entity, url: 'blah blah')
  expect(entity).to have(1).errors_on(:url)
end
```

But the test fails:

```
Failures:

1) Entity is invalid when url format is NOT valid
   Failure/Error: entity = FactoryGirl.build(:entity, url: 'blah blah')
   URI::InvalidURIError:
     bad URI(is not URI?): blah blah
```

It seems like the error isn't being raised in a way that it can be recognized by testing framework.  What am I not understanding?

app/models/entity.rb:

```
require 'uri'
class Entity < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :url, presence: true, uniqueness: true, :format => { :with => URI.regexp }

  ...

  def url=(_link)

    if _link
        uri = URI.parse(_link)

        if (!uri.scheme)
            link = "http://" + _link
        else
            link = _link
        end
      super(link)
    end

  end
end
```

spec/models/entity_spec.rb:

```
describe Entity do

  ...

  it "is invalid when url format is NOT valid" do
    entity = FactoryGirl.build(:entity, url: 'blah blah')
    expect(entity).to have(1).errors_on(:url)
  end

end
```

spec/factories/entity.rb:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :entity do
    name { Faker::Company.name }
    url { Faker::Internet.url }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I used Rspec, but I think you can try something like:

```
expect {
  FactoryGirl.build(:entity, url: 'blah blah')
}.to raise_error(URI::InvalidURIError)
```

*Explanation, for question in comments*

Whenever you call `FactoryGirl.build(:entity, url: 'blah blah')` the [URI library will raise an exception](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/InvalidURIError.html) (your error). The exception will be raised before you can assign it to the `entity` variable. Which causes the test to fail. The `expect` will all catch the exception and check if it is `URI::InvalidURIError`.

Comment: That worked, but why?  When I tried `entity = FactoryGirl.build(:entity, url: 'blah blah')` then `expect(entity).to raise_error(URI::InvalidURIError)`, I get the error listed in my question.

Comment: Hi @craig, glad it worked :) Whenever you call `FactoryGirl.build(:entity, url: 'blah blah')` the URI library will raise an exception (your error). That error will be raised before you can assign it to the `entity` variable. Which causes the test to fail.

Comment: OK, but I have a similar requirement on the `name` property (`validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true`) which is caught using the two-line syntax.  Why the difference?  Obviously, it has something to do with the block in the `:url` requirement.